# how to align Second Item with respect to parent in LinerLayout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am having problem with LinearLayout. I have two items in LinearLayout ..one is Linearlayout with wrapped width and another is simple textview...My wrapped width LinearLayout get width from Activity ..and it is working good..But I have a problem with textview which is second item ..It get start from my wrapped LinearLayout, whatever width my wrapped Layout get, textview start from it.I want to make that textview align in center with respect to Parent Linearlayout.Here is my xml ..`

```
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/graph_panel_bg_one"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/looser_left_jab_force_panel"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:background="@drawable/force_panel_gradient" >
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/looser_left_jab_force"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text=""
                                android:textColor="#F18B86"
                                android:textSize="10sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/graph_panel_bg_one" >

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/looser_left_jab_speed_panel"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:background="@drawable/speed_panel_gradient" >
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/looser_left_jab_speed"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="12222"
                                android:textColor="#CEE2E9"
                                android:textSize="10sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>`
```

Comment: better use relative layout if you want to align things

Comment: change `android:gravity="center"` to `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Comment: Yes it is better to use relative layout , but right now I am in the condition that not able to convert that Linear to relative.. any other help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LinearLayout** is a view group that aligns all children in a single direction, vertically or horizontally. You can specify the layout direction with the android:orientation attribute.

**All children of a LinearLayout are stacked one after the other**, so a vertical list will only have one child per row, no matter how wide they are, and a horizontal list will only be one row high (the height of the tallest child, plus padding). A LinearLayout respects margins between children and the gravity (right, center, or left alignment) of each child.

> > > It get start from my wrapped LinearLayout, whatever width my wrapped Layout get

This is because your parent linear layout "`android:orientation="horizontal`", If you set "android:orientation="vertical" it may get start from your wrapped LinearLayout, whatever height your wrapped Layout gets.

It is probably hard to achieve the way you want through the LinearLayout.

I too suggest to go with Relative Layout. It's helps to align the child the way you want.

Note: Take proper actions of your textview which possible overlaps with the LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Set your TextView width to `"wrap_content"`